# Trim File Names of Tarballs Using Bash

Tags: bash, filenames, bash-scripting

I need to grade some source code from various students. The submission process is through Blackboard which appends to the file name a bunch of unnecessary stuff. Here is an example:

```
Test Submission_adunn_attempt_2014-04-04-10-48-37_adunn-helloworld.tar.gz
```

I would like to rename this file (and all others) to:

```
adunn-helloworld.tar.gz
```

How can I do this in a Bash script?

Comment: What is the logic for _trimming_?

Comment: I only want everything after the final underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use shell parameter expansion:

```
$ s="Test Submission_adunn_attempt_2014-04-04-10-48-37_adunn-helloworld.tar.gz"
$ echo "${s##*_}"
adunn-helloworld.tar.gz
```

Use a loop for renaming the files:

```
for f in *.gz; do
  mv "$f" "${f##*_}"
done
```

Alternatively, you could use `prename` (a part of perl distribution):

```
rename 's/.*_//' *.gz
```

Comment: +1. Note, however, that this script does not check for duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is exactly what I needed. I was actually fairly close with something similar to '${f##*_}', but I do not fully understand the syntax for this type of operation.